# Could a fourth dimension be "spatially simulated" one point at a time by using movements?

Tags: simulations, spacetime-dimensions, geometry

I wonder if time and movement can be translated into a simulation of an extra spatial dimension. At least in one point at a time. I'll try to explain.

Imagine a fixed probe which measures the distance to one point on the surface of a cube. As the cube rotates around its center, the probe will measure different distances to its surface. If the probe starts perpendicularly to a side of the cube, the distance will decrease as the cube rotates. After an edge meets the probe, the distance will start to increase.

This could be simulated by a 2D rectangle if, when the probe meets its edge, the rectangle momentarily turns 90 degrees. The probe would be fooled to think it is measuring a cube.

Could in a similar way a fourth spatial dimension, a hypercube, be simulated by moving a regular cube? Does a hypercube consist of regular cubes, like a cube consists of rectangles?

Comment: in effect you just trace the trajectory of a particle in a lower-dimensional sub-space of the 1+3 manifold

Comment: Yes, but from multiple such traces (one at a time) of an n dimensional object, one can reconstruct a simulated n+1 dimensional object. At least I think so given my simple example. Rotating and tumbling a cube would measure six different rectangles, they could for example have different temperatures, colors or textures. If a hypercube consists of several such cubes, or rectangles, one should be able to simulate it and trace the properties across its "surface". Somehow the time dimension is translated into a fourth static spatial dimension, by means of 3D movement through time.

Comment: The trace **is** the trajectory and it is what you describe. Yes one can do that, still the time component of Minkowski space-time **is not** a space component, simply because it **cannot be rotated to a space component**

Comment: @Nikos M , Let me put it like this. What would such a trajectory trace look like on a simulated hypercube? Or  rather, what shape and movements would be needed to give such a trace? In my simple example it seems to work from 2D to 3D. Couldn't it work for a fourth spatial dimension too?

Comment: There is a little book called ["Geometry, Relativity and the 4th dimension"](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Relativity-Fourth-Dimension-Mathematics/dp/0486234002) which discusses a scenario similar to this. How to describe the trajectory of 1+3-space-time in a higher-dimensional way